# PHP header in CSS file

Tags: php, html, css

I've looked on here and managed to get my `css` file to work with `php`, however when I validate it, I get errors, specifically:

Unknown error org.w3c.www.http.HttpInvalidValueException: Invalid content type.

The file in question is medium.php

The `html` to link to the file reads:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="medium.php" media="screen and (max-width: 1024px)" />
```

The `CSS`/`PHP` file starts like this:

```
  <?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

include 'login.php';

$link = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");
```

Anyone know how to correct this so it formats correctly and does not generate an error please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`charset: UTF-8` is incorrect syntax; replace with `charset=utf-8`.

Comment: +1. Also, delete the whitespace before the opening `<?php` tag in the css/php file

Comment: Thanks Peter, there isn't any however, just happened to copy that way. Annoying.